# Display random images in a fixed position

Tags: javascript

I have 3 images. What i want to do is when i click on any one of the image a random image should be displayed on a div.
Here is the code. Help please.

```js
var iarr=["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"];
function select()
{
  var random=Math.floor(Math.Random()*3);
  document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML = iarr[random];
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <h4> MAKE A CHOICE </h3>
  <img id='x' onclick="select" src='1.jpg'/>
  <img id='y' onclick="select" src='2.jpg'/>
  <img id='z' onclick="select" src='3.jpg'/>
  <div id='disp'/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var iarr=["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"];
function select(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * iarr.length);
    var div = document.getElementById('disp');
    var image = "<img src=\"" + iarr[random] + "\"/>";
    div.innerHTML = image;
}

<html>
<body>
  <h4> MAKE A CHOICE </h4>
  <img id='x' onclick="select()" src='1.jpg'/>
  <img id='y' onclick="select()" src='2.jpg'/>
  <img id='z' onclick="select()" src='3.jpg'/>
  <div id='disp'/>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/pndtdt7t/

Comment: No problem, if that was the answer to what you were looking for, could you mark it as the answer please? Helps other people and myself :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var iarr = [
  "http://www.wallpapers-for-desktop.com/desktopbilder_for_free/free_desktopbild.jpg",
  "http://wikiin.com/media/images/15/04/21/cfe0fdfb23.jpg",
  "http://data.whicdn.com/images/89382997/large.jpg"

];

function select() {

  var img = "<img src=\""+iarr[Math.floor(Math.random() * iarr.length)]+ "\" />";

  document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML = img;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h4> MAKE A CHOICE </h3>
  <img id='x' onclick="select()" src='1.jpg'/>
  <img id='y' onclick="select()" src='2.jpg'/>
  <img id='z' onclick="select()" src='3.jpg'/>
  <div id='disp'/>
```